# System programming: How to gather info?

Tags: c, system-calls, gnu

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/learn-linux-system-programming-by-doing-projects), a good way to learn system programming would be to implement the existing tools. I decided to try to rewrite `ls` and `ps`.

My question is how would one proceed to get documentation for such?

- Where can I find the API of system calls needed to query the kernel, the file system, etc ...
- I thought that maybe I could take a look at the source code of the GNU tools. Where can I find it?
- Are there any (hopefully freely available online) good documentation you guys would recommend as to where to start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) as a reference. It's not for absolute beginners, but if you're reasonably fluent in C you should be able to read a section and write a working program.

You can find the source of the GNU tools on the [GNU website](http://www.gnu.org/software/); the easiest way to get it is to obtain the source packages on your Linux distribution (e.g. `apt-get source coreutils` if your distribution uses Debian packaging utilities). I recommend starting with [BusyBox](http://busybox.net/) rather than the GNU tools. BusyBox is a set of utilities for embedded Linux systems; it's smaller and simpler than the GNU utilities.

You can run `strace ls` to see what system calls `ls` is making. Note that when you write a program, you don't call system calls directly, you call functions in the C library which make system calls. For things like file manipulations, the C library functions like `open` and `read` are pretty close to the system calls though.

For learning, a book (on paper) is usually helpful. [*Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201433079) ([APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/)) is a classic. If you get it, make sure to get the second edition, as the first is quite dated. This book is the reference, but other books may be more suitable for beginners; shop around.

Answer (score 1):

On *linux*, commands as `ps`,`free` and `top` are implemented reading information from ***proc*** file-system.

```
   The proc file system is a pseudo-file system which is used as an inter-
   face to kernel data structures.  It is commonly mounted at /proc.  Most
   of  it  is  read-only,  but  some  files  allow  kernel variables to be
   changed.
```

Start at `man 5 proc` and do not forget that all these utilities are open-source, so you can also peek they [code](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=32494).