# How can I find where a program is installed or run from?

Tags: mysql, services

I installed centos and now I want to get into mysql via the command line, but I forgot my root password for mysql as its not the same as the root password I made to login to the system. I googled and it told me to stop the mysql service to do a password reset, but I dont know where it is. What do I need to type to find out where a service is installed so i can stop it?

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS the way to start/stop service is next:

```
service mysqld start
service mysqld stop
```

P.S. If your version is 7 you can use:

```
systemctl start mysqld
systemctl stop mysqld
```

Comment: And on CentOS 7 you can use `systemctl (start/stop) mysqld`

Answer (score 0):

`service mysql stop` should work. But perhaps you should gain ome basic understanding of linux before using it.

Comment: what is ur suggested reading?

Comment: @duckx http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238/11083 is a similar Q with many good answers.