# What is the best book every Unix or Linux user should read?

Tags: books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended reading to better understand unix/linux internals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80/recommended-reading-to-better-understand-unix-linux-internals)

There are a lot of Unix an Linux books. Then I'm curious to know. which book is popular among Unix or Linux user? (content about programming)

Answer (score 1):

Check "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment (2nd Edition)" and also http://www.openbsd.org/books.html#5