# How to catch hold of Linux basics

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am a windows user and I really want to learn how to use Linux. I know little bit of programming and networking concepts if that helps.

I want to learn everything from scratch. Like what command does what, how to configure etc.

I would really prefer paying for CBT Videos training that books, but if book is recommended, then I don't mind using books either.
I did visit CBTnuggets.com but I really couldn't figure out which training is the most basic one.

Please recommend me few Videos(Preferred), Books and any such material.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can come up with is, install any easy distro (Fedora, Centos, Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint) and use it for your day to day life.
As you become a power user you will ask yourself more and more questions and your skills will improve.
You can also consider doing some reading, like the very nice Tanenbaum book on operating systems (this one is expensive but you can probably find a cheaper one)

[Modern Operating Systems (3rd Edition): Andrew S. Tanenbaum: 9780136006633: Amazon.com: Books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136006639)

or read the books from that post: [Recommended reading to better understand Unix/Linux internals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80/recommended-reading-to-better-understand-unix-linux-internals/112#112)

---

**Edit 1**:
If you are really motivated, you can also try to create your Linux from scratch with the best learning distro ever: [Linux from scratc](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)h

Comment: Okay. I will. Thank you so much. Any more suggestions? :)

Comment: well so far it's already a lot to go through :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "Practical Guide to Linux" by Mark G. Sobell.

A good starting point for learning basic Linux commands and certain fundamental concepts around the Linux OS for a beginner !

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be fist to install desktop Linux and then buy some ARM-based board like [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) or [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) (to name some most popular ones) and install an embedded Linux distro like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) on it.

This way you'll learn, how to configure simple Linux from the very beginning and you will have something to play around with. You can learn various init systems like [Sysv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style), [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) etc.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is not an embedded platform, it's a normal PC (albeit a puny one).

Comment: At least it is not an x86 computer, it is ARM11. If you make a media player from Raspberry Pi, then it is an embedded system.

Comment: In that case, if you make a media player from your laptop it is an embedded system.  TBH I think learning linux basics on the pi will be much more frustrating than learning it on a bigger system, like a desktop.

Comment: ...I'm saying that based on the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). The people with no previous linux experience, logically enough, have the most trouble, and since working on the pi can be slow and awkward, this handicap is multiplied for them there.